# How to run background jobs during cucumber tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

What is the best way to test something that requires background jobs with Cucumber? I need to run DelayedJob and Sneakers workers in background while tests are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has similar problem I ended up writing this (thanks to Square blog post):

```
require "timeout"

class CucumberExternalWorker
  attr_accessor :worker_pid, :start_command

  def initialize(start_command)
    raise ArgumentError, "start_command was expected" if start_command.nil?

    self.start_command = start_command
  end

  def start
    puts "Trying to start #{start_command}..."
    self.worker_pid = fork do
      start_child
    end

    at_exit do
      stop_child
    end
  end

  private

  def start_child
    exec({ "RAILS_ENV" => Rails.env }, start_command)
  end

  def stop_child
    puts "Trying to stop #{start_command}, pid: #{worker_pid}"

    # send TERM and wait for exit
    Process.kill("TERM", worker_pid)

    begin
      Timeout.timeout(10) do
        Process.waitpid(worker_pid)
        puts "Process #{start_command} stopped successfully"
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error
      # Kill process if could not exit in 10 seconds
      puts "Sending KILL signal to #{start_command}, pid: #{worker_pid}"
      Process.kill("KILL", worker_pid)
    end
  end
end
```

This can be called as following (added it to `env.rb` for cucumber):

```
# start delayed job
$delayed_job_worker = CucumberExternalWorker.new("rake jobs:work")
$delayed_job_worker.start
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run any application in the background:

```
    @pid = Process.spawn "C:/Apps/whatever.exe"
    Process.detach(@pid)
```

And even kill it after tests are done:

```
    Process.kill('KILL', @pid) unless @pid.nil?
```

Comment: I need to initialize both delayed job and sneakers in test environment. is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own step definition in `features/step_definitions/whatever_steps.rb` (hopefully with a better name)

```
When /^I wait for background jobs to complete$/ do
  Delayed::Worker.new.work_off
end
```

That can be extended for any other scripts you'd like to run with that step. Then in the test, it goes something like:

```
Then I should see the text "..."
When I wait for background jobs to complete
And I refresh the page
Then I should see the text "..."
```